# Weak formulations: where should the $\forall$ be placed?

Tags: functional-analysis

Shoud I write (with the appropriate assumptions on $b$ and $l$)

- Find $u\in U$ such that $\forall v \in V$, $b(u,v)=l(v)$

or

- Find $u\in U$ such that $b(u,v)=l(v)$, $\forall v \in V$

I tend to go for the first formulation but I often see the second version.

Comment: Find $u\in U$ such that $v \in V \implies b(u,v)=l(v)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're really writing something about logic, you should avoid using so many logic symbols, it looks a bit ugly. I suggest you pick up any math book, and you'll see very rarely a $\forall, \exists, $ etc.

I would just write, in most cases:

> Find $u\in B$ such that for every $v\in V$, it holds that $b(u,v)=l(v)$.

Sure, you can vary in style, or be a bit less verbose, but you should reserve logic symbols for shorthand (writing theorems or proofs **in** some lecture you're giving, so you can write faster(in the cases that you happen to write this symbols, the $\forall$ at the end or in the middle, is perfectly fine (provided you're clear with the order of the quantifiers, etc))).

---

If you really want to write formulas in a true formal manner, [see this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Formation_rules).

Answer (score 3):

A quantified statement would read: $$\exists u \in V\ \forall v \in V\ b(u,v) = l(v).$$

In plain English it would read $$\text{there exists $u \in U$ such that $b(u,v) = l(v)$ for all $v \in V$}.$$

One often sees the quantifiers $\forall$ and $\exists$ used informally in writing to stand for "for every" and "there exists" whenever these expressions occur, as with your second version.

tl;dr the first is more along the lines of a properly formed mathematical sentence but the meaning of the second is perfectly clear.

Comment: Wouldn't the most formal way be $\exists u \, \forall v\, ((u\in V \wedge v\in V) \rightarrow b(u,v)=l(v))$?

Comment: Oh probably. Go ahead and edit the answer if you like. I removed the word properly :P